# Compute Engine unhealthy instance down 50% of the time

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I started to use google cloud 3 days ago or so, so I am completely new to it. 
I have 4 pods deployed to Google Kubernetes Engine:

- Frontend: react app,
- Redis,
- Backend: made up of 2 containers, a nodejs server and a cloudsql-proxy,
- Nginx-ingress-controller

** And also have an sql instance running for my postgresql database, hence the cloudsql-proxy container

This setup works well 50% of the time, but every now and then **all the pods crash or/and the containers are recreated**.

I tried to check all the relevant logs, but I really don't know which are actually relevant. But there is one thing that I found which correlates with my issue, I have 2 VM instances running, and one of them might be the faulty one:

[image]
When I hover the loading spin, it **says Instance is being verified**, and it seems to be in this state 80% of the time, when it is not there is a yellow warning beside the name of the instance, saying **The resource is not ready**.

[image]
Here is the cpu usage of the instance (the trend is the same for all the hardware), I checked in the logs of my frontend and backend containers, here is 
the last logs that correspond to a cpu drop:

> 2019-03-13 01:45:23.533 CET -    Server ready
>
> 2019-03-13 01:45:33.477 CET - 2019/03/13 00:45:33 Client closed local connection on 127.0.0.1:5432
>
> 2019-03-13 01:54:07.270 CET -  yarn run v1.10.1

[image]

**As you can see here, all the pods are being recreated...**

---

I think that it might come from the fact that the faulty instance is unhealthy:

> Instance gke-*****-production-default-pool-0de6d459-qlxk is **unhealthy** for **.**.**.**

...the health check is proceeding and recreating/restarting the instance again and again. *Tell me if I am wrong*.
**So, how can I discover what is making this instance unhealthy?**

Comment: Can you confirm the cluster state is unhealthy after your app deployment? Did you set limits/quota to pods? can you check syslogs, kubelet logs, and run `kubectl describe node <node_name>` to get more info.

Comment: How much CPU/Memory have you given these nodes , have you tried increasing the configuration to see if the issue still persists.Try checking StackDriver to see what might have caused the termination

Comment: Can you look at Stackdriver for logs from these GCE VMs, also as said above `kubectl describe node` might be telling you what's going on. Have you enabled Node Auto-repair on GKE? If not, consider enabling that https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-repair

Comment: Two possibilities come to mind:  (a) Are these preemptable instances?  (b) Are these shared-core instances?  f1-micro in particular can just barely run the basic Kubernetes setup, and if you enable stackdriver on such a cluster you'll frequently see CPU graphs like you showed as the instance gets throttled (leading to the nodes becoming unhealthy)